# JQuery/CSS bubble mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a CSS "Bubble" that I am using as a submenu for a flexbox.

Essentially what I'd like to figure out is if there is a way to extend the "mouseover" area to include the ::before part of my bubble?

I'd like to have it so that when I mouseover my icon that opens my submenu I can mouseover the space in between the bubble and where the menu item that opens it is. Meaning I dont want to mouseover the menu item have it open the submenu and then only be able to get into that submenu if I scroll over the ::before part of that menu. If I open the submenu and scroll in the space between the open bubble and the flexbox (i guess you could call it padding or spacing between) I'd like the submenu to stay open, otherwise if I hover outside of the submenu (with the exception of the spacing that this ::before thing creates) I'd like the submenu to close. It's the spacing between the little pointer on the submenu and the submenu itself that I want to allow for it as part of my mouseover.

```js
$('.submenu').css('display', 'none');

$("div[class*='menuHover']").mouseover(function(i){
  submenu =  $(this).next()

  $(submenu).fadeIn(500, function(e){
    $(this).show();
  }) 
});

$('.menuWrapper').mouseleave(function(){
   $('.submenu').hide();
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 250px;
  height:200px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  font-size:80pt;
  vertical-align:50%;
}

.icon-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  top:45px
}

.menuHover > div i {
  font-size:10pt;
}


.menuHover{
  position:relative;
  top:-160px;
  left:200px;
}

.menuWrapper {
  height:100px; 
  width:70px; 
  cursor:default;
  }

.submenu {
          cursor:default;
          width:200px;
          height:150px;
          position:relative;
          top:-190px;
          left:255px;
          background: #686868;
          border-radius: 10px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 10px 22px;
          vertical-align:top;
          z-index: 15;
          }
          
.submenu::before{
  background-color:#686868;
  content: "\00a0";
  display:block;
  height:16px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  width: 15px;
}          

div.info-link{
padding-left:100px;
display:inline-block;
white-space:nowrap
font-size:12pt;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</br></br></br>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fas fa-user icon"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-wrapper">My Products</div>
    <div class="menuWrapper">
   <div class="menuHover"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
   <div class="submenu">
         Sub-menu 1</br>
        Sub-menu 2</br>       
         Sub-menu 3</br>
  Sub-menu 4</br>
  Sub-menu 5</br>
  <div class="info-link"><a href="#">Go to page</a></div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div>
 <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fas fa-users icon"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-wrapper">My Teams's Products</div>
    <div class="menuWrapper">
   <div class="menuHover"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
   <div class="submenu">
         Sub-menu 1</br>
        Sub-menu 2</br>       
         Sub-menu 3</br>
  Sub-menu 4</br>
  Sub-menu 5</br>
  <div class="info-link"><a href="#">Go to page</a></div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div>
 <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fas fa-search icon"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-wrapper">Search</div>
    <div class="menuWrapper">
   <div class="menuHover"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
   <div class="submenu">
         Sub-menu 1</br>
        Sub-menu 2</br>       
         Sub-menu 3</br>
  Sub-menu 4</br>
  Sub-menu 5</br>
  <div class="info-link"><a href="#">Go to page</a></div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>  
  <div>
 <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar icon"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-wrapper">Stats</div>
    
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It's already doing what you're asking, the problem is that the `:before` is _tiny_ so it's easy to miss it by being a bit to high / low.  If you want a bigger "hot" area for hovering, add a transparent `:after` that covers the space below the bubble "tip"

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just like your `:before` element, just with different positioning and a transparent bg....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use another psuedo-element (`:after`) with positioning / size to fill the desired gap.

For example, given your existing markup, you could add:

```
.submenu:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Modified / updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sk23uc0p/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.